# How to call methods after HttpResponse?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpresponse

I am a bit puzzled at the moment. I have a web application that manipulates a file and then returns the file to a user's browser for download when it's done.

The download part is going well, as I'm using `Response.AddHeader` and `Reponse.BinaryWrite` to push the file back to the browser but I am unable to call any further methods after using Response methods.

I suppose I have not worked with HttpReponse enough to know the trick to this. Perhaps I would be better off using another class or generic handler to handle the download?

My code goes something like...

```
// Methods to be called first

Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();

Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}.pdf", "New_Merged_PDF_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM-dd-yyyy")));
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.BinaryWrite(output.ToArray());
Response.End();

// Methods to be called last (these wont work)
```

Probably something simple that I'm overlooking but I'm still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Once you've send the response you're done.  If you have something to do, you should be doing it before you finish sending your response.  Sounds like whatever you're doing should either be done before you finalize your response, or you should be making a second request to do whatever else you need to do.

Comment: Hmm, I suppose that would be as limiting as `Reponse.Redirect()` where you obviously cant do anything else after that is called? Not that I would want to but generally speaking, the HttpReponse class should always be last?

Comment: HttpResponse is a class not a method.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Of course. I just had my head wrapped around method. ;)

Comment: Very Well, I appreciate everyone's input. I'll make the appropriate adjustments to my application.

Comment: If you were using a debugger you would have found the issue already. Set the debugger to break on all exceptions.

Comment: @usr I have a bad habit of simply building and then refreshing the browser. I guess that would have helped. Although, this it wrapped in a `try` `catch` block and I haven't caught any errors in the corresponding error indicator further down the line.

Comment: The problem is that Response.End aborts the current thread by throwing a TAE. Your debugger and the catch should have noticed this.

Comment: @usr Interesting.. Yes, I would think it would if that where the case. Similar to `Response.Redirect("blah.aspx", true)` I suppose. The methods I wish to call last are in the `finally` block but I guess that wouldn't matter in this case.

Comment: Be sure to read the documentation. [`HttpResponse.End` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end.aspx) tells you exactly what you needed to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a little color to Servy's explaination; there is an order of operations within the HTTP protocol specification.  One of them is that the Headers need to be sent to the client before the Body.  This allows the receiver of the response to properly deal with the Body that is sent based on any Headers.

> The presence of a message-body in a request is signaled by the
> inclusion of a Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding header field in
> the request's message-headers.

[IETF RFC 2616 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4)

One of the few (if the only, I'm not sure) exception is the `Content-Type: multipart/mixed;`

[IETF RFC 1867 - Form-based File Upload in HTML (although Obsolete, examples are still relevant)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1867)

```
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"

Joe Blow
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

... contents of file1.txt ...
--AaB03x--
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. For this, I'll try to find a different way to do the needful before sending the headers. In my case, I want to clear the content of an `<asp:ListBox>` right before the file is downloaded but it hasnt worked.

Comment: One way to do that is to send down JSON to the client (jQUery) that includes everything you need, including a URL to the download, then jQuery can clear the box and redirect to the URL which would start the download (and the client would stay on the same page).

Comment: I feel like an idiot now but indeed, jQuery (or JS in general) was an option I should have looked at all along for something as simple as what I needed to do. I was hellbent on getting C# to work though...  `function ClearMergeList() {
                                                    document.getElementById("<%= PDFmerge_FileListBox.ClientID %>").options.length = 0;
                                                }`

Comment: After your first comment, I should have mentioned that you original question is actual an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/171858).  Do be careful not to fall into that trap.